# Why QTableView extended selection ignores my default selected row?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

The first row is selected by default, when I shift-select the last row I expect that all rows will be selected but no, **it only selects the visible rows of the QTableView**.

I have a QTableView displaying data from a database-model. It is configured to allow extended selection (ctrl, shift etc) and to select rows only (not cells). The content is changing based on other parameters, and whenever I update the model I select by default the first row of my QTableView.

```
ui->tableView->setModel(model);

ui->tableView->setColumnHidden(UidColumn, true);

ui->tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
ui->tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui->tableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);

ui->tableView->verticalHeader()->hide();
ui->tableView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);

// This is done whenever the content changes
QModelIndex index = model->index(0,0);
ui->tableView->setCurrentIndex(index);
```

I hide the vertical headers because nothing to display there, and I hide the first column because it is not relevant for the user.

The first row is displayed as selected, I even logged the changes of focus and the `tableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows()` is always good (i.e. returning `QModelIndex(0,0)`). But when I do the shift-click on the last row, it is like the first row was never selected at all.

If I manually select the first row (or any row), the next shift-click will work perfectly. If I do a ctrl-click, the multiselection works perfectly. It is like my default selection (done by the code) is ignored with shift-click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `QModelIndex(0,0)` selects a cell that is part of the hidden column. Even if displayed as a selected row, apparently it messes up the shift-selection.

If I do not hide the first column, it works fine.

If I use `QModelIndex index = model->index(0,1);` it works fine.

**A simpler solution** is to do `ui->tableView->selectRow(0);`